# another way to handle dynamic sort

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Given:

You can sort result set by indicating index of column.

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS ORDERY BY 1
```

I'm trying to use in the following context, however, I get error message:

> Msg 5308, Level 16, State 1, Line 8 
>   Windowed functions do not support integer indices as ORDER BY clause expressions.

```
EXEC ("
SELECT  *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY 1 ) AS 'Seq'   
from dynamic_table");
```

Can you think of a work-around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the column name this should work:

```
Exec ("
select *, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY " + columnName + " ) AS 'Seq'   
from dynamic_table");
```

If the column name is not known:

```
DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(100) = 'test'
DECLARE @column_name nvarchar(100) 
SELECT 
    @column_name = columns.name
FROM sys.columns
inner join sys.tables ON tables.object_id = columns.object_id
WHERE tables.name = @table_name and column_id = 1

EXEC ('
select *, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ' + @column_name + ' ) AS ''Seq''   
from ' + @table_name);
```

Comment: I'm currently passing column name as parameter. I want a way where if I don't pass parameter it chooses the first column of whatever table is passed in.

Comment: @Rod Have you thought of querying the name from the schema?

Comment: Thanks for all the insight.